# Use of foreach in the Controller and use of output it in the view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter. How can put foreach in the Controller and use only of output it in the view.(i not want put foreach in the view) ?

```
foreach ($output->result() as $row)
{
    echo '<option>'.$row->name.'</option>';
}
```

This is my view now:

```
<select>
<option disabled="disabled" value="">selected</option>
<?php 
foreach ($output->result() as $row) { 
   echo '<option>'.$row->name.'</option>'; 
} 
?>
</select>
```

I want this in the view:

```
<select>
<option disabled="disabled" value="">selected</option>
<?php 
    echo $output_foreach_from_Controller; 
?>
```

Comment: I think that foreach in the VIEW is better. Because working with HTML in controller is a bad practice. http://plutov.by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the **logic wants the foreach to be inside the view** (it's a presentational thing, after all, and Controllers shouldn't do any data manipulation of sorts. Since you're using a db method, you might want to put that in the model, although "logically" wrong too...)

Anyway, coming to your question...You can assign it to a variable, and pass that to the view:

In controller:

```
function whatever()
{
$string = '';

foreach ($output->result() as $row) { 
   $string .= '<option>'.$row->name.'</option>'; 
} 

$data['foreach_output'] = $string;

$this->load->view('viewfile',$data);
}
```

in view:

```
<select>
<?php echo $foreach_output;?>
</select>
```

Comment: if there is not `'<option>'`, and there is only `$string .= $row->name;` how is it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use 'form_dropdown' form_helper.
See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html
I hope this help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the controller you can assign the value ... to a variable and then pass that variable to the view. See something like given below:

```
<?php 

$variable = "";

foreach ($output->result() as $row) {
   $variable = $variable . '<option>'.$row->name.'</option>';
}

$data["option_values"] = $variable;

$this->load->view('view-name', $data);

?>
```

And then echo the "$option_values" variable in the view where you wan

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really put the foreach in the view. You can also use the template version of foreach to make it look nicer:

```
<select>
    <option disabled="disabled" value="">selected</option>
    <?php foreach ($output->result() as $row): ?>
    <option><?php echo $row->name.; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</select>
```

The reason for this is that if you generate HTML in the controller it's not immediately obvious what is being output.